# default blank for boolean dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an application where users can create apartment listings.

The form asks users to specify whether there is an agent fee and if the apartment is furnished.

In the apartment form partial (which is rendered in the create and edit apartment views), I have two dropdown menus for these boolean variables (furnished and agent_fee).

I validate that these variables are present in the model validation:

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validate :agent_fee_and_furnished_are_present
    def agent_fee_and_furnished_are_present
        if agent_fee.nil?
          errors.add(:agent_fee, "You must specify if there is an agent fee")
        end
        if furnished.nil?
          errors.add(:furnished, "You must specify if the apartment is furnished")
        end
    end 
end
```

(I created a custom validation so FALSE would be allowed. If I validated the presence of the variables, FALSE would fail the .blank test that ruby runs.)

**My question is, how can I include a blank option as the first option in the dropdowns that will work in the create AND edit views?**

(I want to do this so the user is forced to select one of the options, and doesn't end up with a default because that's what was the first in the dropdown)

I tried:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :agent_fee, "Is there an agent fee?" %><br>
    <%= f.select :agent_fee, options_for_select([['Yes', true], ['No', false]]), {:prompt => ""} %>
  </div>
```

However, when this field is rendered in the edit apartment view, there is a blank prompt present, even if the agent_fee for an apartment the apartment was FALSE. (It seems that rails does a similar .blank? test which only overrides the prompt if the value is TRUE)

**So again, my question is, how can I include a blank option as the first option in the dropdowns that will work in the edit view (and only be displayed if the agent_fee variable is NIL and not FALSE)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `include_blank` in the `f.select` call:

```
<%= f.select :agent_fee, options_for_select([['Yes', true], ['No', false]]), { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. When I use include_blank, the blank option is ALWAYS displayed, even if the value was TRUE. According to the docs in form_options_helper.rb, the main difference is that if the select already has a value, then :prompt will not show whereas the :include_blank always will.